# Same offset in the tableview but difference position?

Tags: ios, tableview

Same offset in the tableview but difference position?

I reloaddata in the tableview.
I find a problem that the tableview will move to another row sometimes.

So I save the offset before reloaddata and set it to the same offset.

But finally its has the same offset but different position.
Whats going on?

```
    CGPoint point = [self.listtableview contentOffset];
    NSLog(@"piont when appear  = %f",point.y );

    [self.listtableview performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [self.listtableview setContentOffset:point];
    CGPoint point2 = [self.listtableview contentOffset];
    NSLog(@"piont when appear2  = %f",point2.y );
```

I found out point.y = point2.y
But the table is in different position.

Comment: Why are you performing on main thread instead of directly? Shouldn't make a difference, but does it?

Comment: its the same result

Comment: The cells are a different distance from, say the top of the window right? What happens if you hook down into an individual cell and measure that distance, relative to the window?